# Tailwind width dosn't work with breakpoints

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, breakpoints

I'm a total beginner to **tailwind**, and I decided to rebuild one of my projects with it in React. I have a grid with **2 columns**, that should align next to each other horizontally, instead of vertically when the screen reaches the breakpoint.

My problem is that when I set the width to fit the screen, which as far as I know, should make each column fill the screen. Then the first column should push down the 2. under it. But it doesn't, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 h-screen">
    <div className="justify-center items-center flex flex-col lg:w-screen">
        <h1 id="elsoszoveg-cim" className="text-5xl tracking-wide font-medium text-center pb-9">...Mi Pixie?</h1>
        <p className="text-center text-2xl md:w-screen">
            Pixie egy személyes projekt, amelyet azért fejlesztettem, 
            hogy a különböző elfoglaltságaimat egyesíteni tudjam.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div className=" bg-sky-100">
    </div>
</div>
```

*So basically I want my 2 columns to be **below each other** after the breakpoint.*

Comment: What exactly ["doesn't work"?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying your breakpoints to the `width` of your elements, change the number of `columns` you have in your grid. For example, by having two columns on smaller screens and 1 column on wider screens `grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-1`.

```html
<div class="grid h-screen grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-1">
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <h1 id="elsoszoveg-cim" class="pb-9 text-center text-5xl font-medium tracking-wide">...Mi Pixie?</h1>
    <p class="text-center text-2xl">Pixie egy személyes projekt, amelyet azért fejlesztettem, hogy a különböző elfoglaltságaimat egyesíteni tudjam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-sky-100"></div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/n8YUXqli7W)

Comment: This worked! Thanks, I haven't thought about using another way instead of changing the width of the elements.